# "To" + infinitive for purpose

Tags: to-infinitive

Does "to" in the following sentence express purpose?

He could not bring himself **to** believe that his father had really died.

Comment: I would say that it was part of the infinitive (to believe).

Comment: Yes, I would like to know whether it is an infinitive marker that holds the meaning of purpose? @KateBunting

Comment: The basic assertion here is *He **could / did** not believe that...*, so I'd say ***bring himself to*** is an almost meaningless bit of circumlocution (within which ***to*** looks like a preposition, not an infinitive marker). But I suppose you could say the "purpose" of him (unsuccessfully) bringing himself to think something (*persuading* himself of something) is to actually believe the "unbelievable truth".

Comment: In this context, do you see a *purpose* in believing his father had died?

Answer (score 0):

He could not bring himself to believe that his father had really died.

Here **to believe** is not an Infinitive of purpose

The sentence implies–**he could not force himself to believe that his father had really died.**

Comment: Why do you think it's an infinitive of purpose? What's the purpose?